# Can I set a notification when Google Analytics data has finished exporting?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm exporting google analytics data to BigQuery.

Is it possible to set a notification that export of GA data is complete?

Comment: How are you exporting? If your using the Data transfer Service it has a function to send notification emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is kind of possible. You need Stackdriver Logging and Pub/Sub. You export logging [events that the user "analytics-processing-dev@system.gserviceaccount.com"](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092) triggers [from Stackdriver to Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2). From Pub/Sub you [push the messages](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) to a URL with a service behind - e.g. you can build a chatbot or mailing service.
But there is no out of the box notification system afaik.